# How to get the output into a json format?

Tags: python, json, bottle

Code:::

```
from bottle import route, request, response, template,run
import petl as etl
@route('/loc')
def abc():
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin']='*'
    response.headers['Content-type']='application/json'
    post = request.query.postcode
    locationTable = etl.fromcsv('clinic_locations.csv')
    abcd = etl.search(locationTable, 'Postcode', post)
    return template('{{postcode}}',postcode=abcd)
```

Here is the [csv](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Erkx0MGaJr87F3g0r--eUM0LxzwNTfXG) File ,I want to get the result in json but i dont know to do i get it beacuse I am very new to petl and bottle framework
When user enter the url on the browser e.g "localhost:8080/loc?postcode=4700" it will return  the data regarding to that postal code but in csv format but i want to get the output in json format so i can user this data to find the address on the map
Can any one help me to get the result

Example: My desired ouput on browser after running localhost by bottle framework is:

[image]

**Updated**
But what I am getting is this:
[image]

Comment: Can you share what your output looks like now?

Comment: Just to let you know, indentation matters in Python.

Comment: yes i know i want to get the output in json can you help me

Comment: @NitikeshDubey What is the etl module? Please give a [minimal, complete, and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) answer.

Comment: updated the question!!

Comment: i am using petl framework and bottle framework and i need the json by using this framework

Comment: @NitikeshDubey - have you tried the [tojson](http://petl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/io.html#petl.io.json.tojson) method

Comment: yes but it will create the json file but i want to show the json data on the browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the table to JSON like this, it requires that you use the `json` module. This was created from looking around in the `petl` module source.

```
from bottle import route, request, response, template,run
import petl as etl
import json
@route('/loc')
def abc():
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin']='*'
    response.headers['Content-type']='application/json'
    post = request.query.postcode
    locationTable = etl.fromcsv('clinic_locations.csv')
    abcd = etl.search(locationTable, 'Postcode', post)
    abcd = json.JSONEncoder().encode(list(etl.dicts(abcd))) #Here's where the magic happens.
    return abcd
```

If you end up using this answer be sure your database is filtered of all `<script>` tags or else a malicious user could insert JavaScript into your database and make your API endpoint run arbitrary JavaScript otherwise known as an XSS attack.

Comment: thankyou so much but browser shows this----[{&quot;ID&quot;: &quot;25&quot;, &quot;Name&quot;: &quot;Booie Clinic&quot;, &quot;Suburb&quot;: &quot;Booie&quot;, &quot;State&quot;: &quot;QLD&quot;, &quot;Postcode&quot;: &quot;4610&quot;, &quot;Email&quot;: &quot;mailto:booie@myclinic.com.au&quot;, &quot;Lat&quot;: &quot;-26.498426&quot;, &quot;Lon&quot;: &quot;151.935421&quot;}]

Comment: @NitikeshDubey You will need to return just abcd instead of templating. The template function will escape the return. I'll edit my answer to fix this.

Comment: why  &quot; is showing isntead of ("") these quotation

Comment: @NitikeshDubey `&quot;` is the escape sequence for `"` in HTML. Bottle is rightfully escaping this to keep XSS from happening with the JSON. Be sure your database is filtered of all `<script>` tags or else a malicious user could insert javascript into your db and make your api endpoint run arbitrary js. Please click the "check" next to the answer if it was helpful.

Comment: You are right about the XSS. I didn't think about that in my code. *typing the filter up* @MustacheMoses

Comment: @TheOneWhoMade duplicates?

Answer (score 1):

So two things, you should be using json.dumps as your output.  And bottle will always escape the output to make it safe.  To bypass this, you should load a template calling a variable.  Then inside the template, access the variable like so:
   {{!variable_name}}

!! This is very dangerous if the data is user input related, since they could easily insert runable code onto your page.  Use with caution!!